# How to return the maximum value for a given day in python django

Tags: python, django

I have two apis that return doctor list and nurses list. Each doctor/nurse has a field amount for the amount of money in their account.My aim is to return the nurse/doctor with the highest amount of money on a given day, since these values will change when money is earned/withdrawn.Basically I need to return the max value from doctors and nurses, and then return the maximum of those two as well.I have tried Max in django and order_by but there seems to be more that I need to do to achieve the desired result.I will appreciate if anyone can spare sometime to take me through how to achieve this.The apis that return this data look smt like:

```
"doctors": [
          {"name": kev
           "amount": 100.00},
           {"name": dave
           "amount": 200.00}
          ]
 "nurses": [
          {"name": brian
           "amount": 150.00},
           {"name": mary
           "amount": 90.00}
          ]
```

Comment: if you keep `doctors` and `nurses` in one table in `database` then you should do it with `SQL query`. If you have only data like in your question then you can try `max(data['doctors'], key=lambda person: person['amount'])` and the same for `nurses` and later you should have only two values to compare - so it should not be problem for you.

Comment: better show in question (not in comment) code which you used to do it. Put it as text, not image. And if you get error message then show full error message in question (also as text, not image).

Comment: Thanks @furas. This works fine but some of the data has amount as null and throws an error. How can I validate and avoid the error

Comment: is this string `null` or value `None` ? For `None` maybe it would work with `or` - `key=lambda person:(person["amount"] or 0)` - use `0` instead of `None`.  For other value you would have to write normal function witho `if/else` and use this function instead of `lambda`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you keep `doctors` and `nurses` in one table in `database` then you should do it with `SQL query`.

---

If you have `data` like in your question then you can try

```
max(data['doctors'], key=lambda person: person['amount'])
```

and the same for nurses

and later you should have only two values to compare - so it should not be problem for you.

---

Minimal working code:

```
data = {
    "doctors": [
      {"name": "kev",  "amount": 100.00},
      {"name": "dave", "amount": 200.00},
    ],
    "nurses": [
      {"name": "brian", "amount": 150.00},
      {"name": "mary",  "amount": 90.00}
    ]
}

max_doctor = max(data["doctors"], key=lambda person:person["amount"])    
max_nurse = max(data["nurses"], key=lambda person:person["amount"])    

print('max_doctor:', max_doctor)
print('max_nurse:', max_nurse)

max_person = max([max_doctor, max_nurse], key=lambda person:person["amount"])    

print('max_person:', max_person)
```

Result:

```
max_doctor: {'name': 'dave', 'amount': 200.0}
max_nurse: {'name': 'brian', 'amount': 150.0}
max_person: {'name': 'dave', 'amount': 200.0}
```

---

**EDIT:**

If you want only max person then you can also conver `doctors` and `nurses` into one list

```
persons = data["doctors"] + data["nurses"]
```

and use `max` onlu once

```
 max_person = max(persons, key=lambda person:person["amount"])
```

---

```
data = {
    "doctors": [
      {"name": "kev",  "amount": 100.00},
      {"name": "dave", "amount": 200.00},
    ],
    "nurses": [
      {"name": "brian", "amount": 150.00},
      {"name": "mary",  "amount": 90.00}
    ]
}

persons = data["doctors"] + data["nurses"]

max_person = max(persons, key=lambda person:person["amount"])    

print('max_person:', max_person)
```

---

**EDIT:**

If you have `"amount": None` then you can use `(person["amount"] or 0)` to use `0` instead of `None` in `lambda

```
key=lambda person:(person["amount"] or 0)
```

---

```
data = {
    "doctors": [
      {"name": "kev",  "amount": 100.00},
      {"name": "dave", "amount": 200.00},
      {"name": "Joe Doe", "amount": None},
    ],
    "nurses": [
      {"name": "brian", "amount": 150.00},
      {"name": "mary",  "amount": 90.00},
      {"name": "Jane Doe", "amount": None},
    ]
}

persons = data["doctors"] + data["nurses"]

max_person = max(persons, key=lambda person:(person["amount"] or 0))

print('max_person:', max_person)
```

---

If you have `"amount": "null"` or other value then it will be simpler (and more readable) to create normal function instead of `lambda`

```
def get_amount(person):
    amount = person["amount"]

    if isinstance(amount, (float, int)):
        return amount

    return 0

max_person = max(persons, key=get_amount)
```

---

```
data = {
    "doctors": [
      {"name": "kev",  "amount": 100.00},
      {"name": "dave", "amount": 200.00},
      {"name": "Joe Doe", "amount": None},
    ],
    "nurses": [
      {"name": "brian", "amount": 150.00},
      {"name": "mary",  "amount": 90.00},
      {"name": "Jane Doe", "amount": "null"},
    ]
}

persons = data["doctors"] + data["nurses"]

def get_amount(person):
    amount = person["amount"]

    if isinstance(amount, (float, int)):
        return amount

    return 0  # use `0` instead of any other value

max_person = max(persons, key=get_amount)

print('max_person:', max_person)
```

---

**EDIT:**

The same with `pandas`. Using `sort` I can even get ie. 3 persons with max  amount

```
data = {
    "doctors": [
      {"name": "kev",  "amount": 100.00},
      {"name": "dave", "amount": 200.00},
      {"name": "Joe Doe", "amount": None},
    ],
    "nurses": [
      {"name": "brian", "amount": 150.00},
      {"name": "mary",  "amount": 90.00},
      {"name": "Jane Doe", "amount": "null"},
    ]
}

persons = data["doctors"] + data["nurses"]

import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(persons)
print('--- df at start ---')
print(df)

# --------------------------------------------

# put `0` in place of `None` and `"null"`
df['amount'] = df['amount'].fillna(0).replace('null', 0)
print('--- df after replacings ---')
print(df)

# --------------------------------------------

#mask = (df['amount'] == df['amount'].max())
#result = df[ mask ]
result = df[ df['amount'] == df['amount'].max() ]

print('--- result using max ---')
print(result)

# --------------------------------------------

#mask = (df['amount'] == df['amount'].max())
#result = df[ mask ]
result = df.sort_values('amount', ascending=False)

print('--- 3 results using sort ---')
print(result[:3])
```

Comment: I added example with `None` and `"null"`

Comment: I added example with `pandas` - now I can get ie. 3 persons with max `amount`